# Currency converter built with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular.js, unit-conversion

I am fairly new to AngularJS and I am trying to improve my knowledge of this JavaScript Framework by building small real-world web-apps.

In this case, I have built a currency converter app with harnesses an exchange rate API built by me which runs [here.](http://api.decoded.cf/currency.php?from=inr&to=usd&amount=1)

I want to know whether there exists a scope of improvement and optimization in my code.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('QConvert', ['qconvertctrlmodule']);
```

**qconvertctrl.js**

```
var app = angular.module('qconvertctrlmodule', [])
    .controller('QConvertController', function($scope, $http, $log, $interval) {

        $scope.currencyObject = {
                from : "",
                to  : "",
                amount : "",
                amount_converted : "",
                exchangeRate : ""
        };

        $scope.currencyCodes = [{value : 'INR', display : 'Indian Rupee'}, {value : 'USD', display : 'US Dollar'}, {value : 'GBP', display : 'British Pound'}];

        $scope.getexchangerate = function() {

            $log.info("FROM : " + $scope.currencyObject.from);

            $log.info("TO : " + $scope.currencyObject.to);

            $http.get("http://api.decoded.cf/currency.php", {params : {from : $scope.currencyObject.from,
                to : $scope.currencyObject.to, amount : 1}})
                .then(function(response) {

                    $scope.currencyObject.exchangeRate = response.data.amount_converted;

                    $log.info(response.data.amount_converted);


            });

        };


        $interval(function() {
            $scope.getexchangerate();
            console.log('Exchange rates refreshed!');
        }, 5000);

    });

app.filter('toDecimal', function() {
    return function(input, precision) {
        return input.toFixed(precision);
    };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>QConvert</h1>
      </div>
      <p class="lead">A Seamless Currency Converter</p>
      <div class="row" ng-controller="QConvertController">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="amount" ng-model="currencyObject.amount">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="from">From</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="from" ng-model="currencyObject.from" ng-change="getexchangerate()">
                <option ng-repeat="currencyCode in currencyCodes" value="{{currencyCode.value}}">{{currencyCode.display}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="to">To</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="to" ng-model="currencyObject.to" ng-change="getexchangerate()">
                <option ng-repeat="currencyCode in currencyCodes" value="{{currencyCode.value}}">{{currencyCode.display}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" ng-show="currencyObject.amount">
            <h3 class="display-4" ng-If="currencyObject.from != currencyObject.to">{{currencyObject.amount}} {{currencyObject.from}} <span ng-show="currencyObject.to">=</span> <span ng-show="(currencyObject.amount * currencyObject.exchangeRate)">{{(currencyObject.amount * currencyObject.exchangeRate)  | toDecimal:3}}</span> {{currencyObject.to}}</h3>
            <h3 class="display-4" ng-If="(currencyObject.from == currencyObject.to && currencyObject.from !== undefined && currencyObject.to !== undefined)">{{currencyObject.amount}} {{currencyObject.from}} = {{currencyObject.amount}} {{currencyObject.from}}</h3>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

The app is running live [here.](http://dvlup.xyz/)

Comment: Consider using the `currency` filter to display the numbers with currency symbols as prefixes.

Comment: the only input I really have is you could use the angular [$number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) filter as opposed to this custom one you've built.

Answer (score 1):

## Feedback #1:

Angular can actually build the select for you without the repeat via the [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) attribute directive:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        id="to" 
        ng-model="currencyObject.to" 
        ng-change="getexchangerate()" 
        ng-options="currencyCode.value as currencyCode.display for currencyCode in currencyCodes"></select>
```

## Feedback #2:

Angular provides a filter for formatting numbers, [$number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number), so no need to write your own.

## Feedback #3:

Use proper camelCase for function names (i.e. `getExchangeRate` instead of `getexchangerate`). As well as don't mix your snake_case and camelCase. Use snake_case for CONSTANTS (of which you have none) (i.e. `$scope.currencyObject.amountConverted` instead of `$scope.currencyObject.amount_converted`).

## Feedback #4:

Remove unused `$scope` properties.  You never set nor call `$scope.currencyObject.amount_converted`, so get rid of it.

## Feedback #5:

You're making a request without having all of your `params`.  If I change the value of the first select, but haven't changed the value of the second you are firing the promise each time.  This can easily be fixed with a simple `if` statement:

```
// Set initial values null, so they return false.
$scope.currencyObject = {
  from : null,
  to  : null,
  amount : 0,
  exchangeRate : null
}

$scope.getExchangeRate = function() {
  $log.info("FROM : " + $scope.currencyObject.from);
  $log.info("TO : " + $scope.currencyObject.to);
  var options = {
    url: 'http://api.decoded.cf/currency.php',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
      from : $scope.currencyObject.from,
      to : $scope.currencyObject.to, 
      amount : $scope.currencyObject.amount
    }
  };
  if ($scope.currencyObject.from && $scope.currencyObject.to) {
    $http(options).then(function(response) {
      $scope.currencyObject.exchangeRate = response.data.amount_converted;
      $log.info(response.data.amount_converted);
    });
  }    
};
```

## Feedback #6:

You have no error handling around your `$http` request, but on an app this simplistic that may be by design.